# Trouble Debugging NSTimer

Tags: debugging, swift, nstimer

I am trying to have an image show up for 1 second and disappear after the 1 second is up. When I build my app it works fine but when I run my app it crashes. Here is my code:

```
var flashTimer = NSTimer()
var timerCounter = 0
var currentTime = 0
var randomImageGeneratorNumber = 0
var flashingImageView = UIImageView()
var flashButton = UIButton()

@IBAction func flashButton(sender: UIButton) {

    var randomImageGeneratorNumber = arc4random_uniform(6) + 1
    if flashButton.hidden {
        flashButton.hidden = true
        flashingImageView.hidden = false
    }
    if randomImageGeneratorNumber == 1 {
        flashingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image1.png")
    }
    if randomImageGeneratorNumber == 2 {
        flashingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image2.png")
    }
    if randomImageGeneratorNumber == 3 {
        flashingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image3.png")
    }
    if randomImageGeneratorNumber == 4 {
        flashingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image4.png")
    }
    if randomImageGeneratorNumber == 5 {
        flashingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image5.png")
    }
    if randomImageGeneratorNumber == 6 {
        flashingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image6.png")
    }
    var currentTime = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "timerFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    func timerFunc(sender: AnyObject){
        flashingImageView.hidden = true;
    }
}
```

The error in the debugger output is:
[Flash_Facts.ViewController timerFunc]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ceb774810

I am not sure how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have to create your function outside the IBAction function. The same applies to your timer var ( currentTime )

```
var currentTime = NSTimer()
func timerFunc() {
     flashButton.hidden = !flashButton.hidden
     flashingImageView.hidden = !flashingImageView.hidden
}
@IBAction func flashButton(sender: UIButton) {
     flashButton.hidden = !flashButton.hidden
     flashingImageView.hidden = !flashingImageView.hidden
     flashingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image\(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1).png")
     currentTime = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "timerFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}
```

Comment: I want the button to start the timer. If I put the NSTimer outside the IBAction will the button still start the timer or not?

Comment: You need to declare your vars just below your IBOutlets

Comment: If if flashButton.hidden  == true { flashButton.hidden = true } makes no sense

Comment: if you would like to toggle it just use flashButton.hidden = !flashButton.hidden

Comment: Will the button generate a new image and restart the timer every time I click it?

Comment: Do you need it to stay toggling it on and off every second ?

Comment: No. I just need the button to generate an image every time I click it.

Comment: So you just want it to display a random image for 1 second and then hide it?

Comment: Can you explain to me why you have the arc4random_uniform inside the image name. Just for future reference

Comment: this is called String interpolation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: The button will not show up after I press it once. How to I get it to show up again after the image is view?

Comment: Do you want the button available at all time ?

Comment: I don't want the button to be available when the image is being viewed

Comment: make sure there is an exlamation mark in front of it "flashButton.hidden = !flashButton.hidden'

Comment: My bad. I misspelled hidden. Forgot the n